# Excel: Create slicer based on table row

Tags: excel

Is it possible to create a slicer based on a table header row rather than just a header column, like in the mockup below? Or can someone recommend a better way to organize this two-axis data matrix?

I expect the table may be hundreds of entries long, and it would be useful to easily compare just a small subset of materials.

[image: Two-axis data matrix with slicer for both header column and row]

Comment: This is possible with some VBA code, see [Hide & Unhide (Filter) Columns with a Slicer or Filter Drop-down Menu](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/hide-unhide-columns-slicer-filter/)

Comment: Whoa, I think that's exactly what I needed @tjejojyj! I've left the job where I was working on this so can't test it, but it definitely looks like it would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with some VBA code, see [Hide & Unhide (Filter) Columns with a Slicer or Filter Drop-down](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/hide-unhide-columns-slicer-filter/)   I should say I haven't tested this myself but the code is straight forward and self evident.

You would need to adapt the code but the basic set up is :

1. a `Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As
   PivotTable)`  macro in the worksheet that contains the pivot-table.

... which calls ...

2. a longer macro which iterates through the columns and hides those that don't match your criteria.

The code they give isn't particularly complicated (see below) but I think it would be challenging, but not impossible, for a VBA novice to figure out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
'Run the filter columns macro when the pivot table or slicer is changed

    Select Case Target.Name
        Case "PivotTable1"
            Call m_FilterCol.Filter_Columns("rngQuarter", "Report", "Report", "PivotTable1", "Quarter")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Here is Filter_Columns macro code.

```
Sub Filter_Columns(sHeaderRange As String, _
                    sReportSheet As String, _
                    sPivotSheet As String, _
                    sPivotName As String, _
                    sPivotField As String _
                    )

Dim c As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim pi As PivotItem


    'Unhide all columns
    Worksheets(sReportSheet).Range(sHeaderRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    'Loop through each cell in the header range and compare to the selected filter item(s).
    'Hide columns that are not selected/filtered out.

    For Each c In Worksheets(sReportSheet).Range(sHeaderRange).Cells

        'Check if the pivotitem exists
        With Worksheets(sPivotSheet).PivotTables(sPivotName).PivotFields(sPivotField)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set pi = .PivotItems(c.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        'If the pivotitem exists then check if it is visible (filtered)
        If Not pi Is Nothing Then
            If pi.Visible = False Then

                'Add excluded items to the range to be hidden
                If rCol Is Nothing Then
                    Set rCol = c
                Else
                    Set rCol = Union(rCol, c)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        'Reset the pivotitem
        Set pi = Nothing

    Next c

    'Hide the columns of the range of excluded pivot items
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        rCol.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```